# Can not create a multi project build

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to create a Play application with a back end and a front end(using Scala.js). I separated the code into `client` and `server` folders.

For creating a `Multi Project Build` I looked at this http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html and make my `build.sbt` like this:

```
name := """ScalaWeb"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7",

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    jdbc,
    cache,
    ws,
    specs2 % Test
  ),

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19",
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value force(),
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.148"
  ),

  libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0",

  /*libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0",
  libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.12"
  libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"*/

  resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",

  // Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
  // other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
  routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,

  scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath",

  // use this if you just want jawn's parser, and will implement your own facade
  libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "jawn-parser" % "0.8.3",

  // use this if you want jawn's parser and also jawn's ast
  libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "jawn-ast" % "0.8.3",

  //for reading Json libraries
  libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.2.1"
)

lazy val server = (project in file("server")).settings(
  commonSettings: _*
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val client = (project in file("client")).settings(
  commonSettings: _*
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

fork in run := true
```

So basically I placed all dependencies into `commonSettings` and the imported that into the `client` and `server` projects.

However, I am getting this error:

```
[error] (scalaweb/compile:backgroundRun) No main class detected.
```

Why is this occuring?
Have I set up my `build.sbt` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your root project (scalaweb) doesn't have a main class.

You can either:

1. run server's run command by doing: server/run
2. aggregate client and server under root project
   (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation)

This might do what you wish.

Comment: I have added `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(client, server)` to `build.sbt`. I even created a dummy class in both projects which only contains `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
}`. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: No, if I type `activator` and then `server run` I get `[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: server (similar: set)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected '/' (if selecting a project)
[error] Expected configuration`

Comment: it has to be server/run (remember the /)

Comment: I get `not found: value routes` so it seems not to see the routes. But it appears that your instructions solved the previous problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used play framework for a while, prefer akka-http/spray - more scalaish for me